# Can I cut my pineapple (Ananas?) leaves?

Tags: leaves, pruning, pineapple

[image]I have been growing a pineapple in my house. Maybe for 5-6 years. Now my pineapple is too tall and sharp. Unfortunately I can not grow it in outside. So I wanna cut it for safety. Can I cut my pineapple leaves? I really worry. Will it die, after I cut it.

Comment: Do you have a picture of the situation?

Comment: OK! I have picture of my pineapple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can cut your leaves without the plant dying. Pruning pineapple plants is common for the very reason you're describing. If you have fruit growing (which it doesn't look like you do), then you would wait 1-2 months until after harvesting it.

Here's a link that describes the pruning in more detail-
https://homeguides.sfgate.com/times-prune-pineapples-guavas-33717.html

Comment: At first, Thank you! I wanted fruit, but my pineapple never produce it..  Then can i cut now? I am in winter season. and a... can i cut in half? like 1/2?

Comment: I would try cutting it now near the top string that you have tied around it. This should give it plenty of remaining leaves to keep growing. The fact that you've had it this long is a good sign that it's a hardy plant. Clear away any dead leaves towards the bottom as well.  If you like my answer, would you mind upvoting it, please? I wish you and your pineapple plant well.

Comment: Oh then i can a lot of leaves! If i cut leaves on up to string that tied top. And does upvoting mean clicking V icon? I did. And i clicked [this answer is useful]

Answer (score 0):

Hi I’m Betty and I’ve been growing my pineapple for about 6 to 7 years now and not once has it gave me a pineapple it’s very big and beautiful but no fruit yet could there be a reason why.

Comment: Hi, this site is different.  Please ask your own question instead of using the answer box.